# Techniques for hyperparameter search in non-stationary environments

Tags: hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm tuning a supervised machine learning model over time, also called incremental learning. I do not want to assume the environment is non-stationary.

Grid search and random search do not appear to be the best choices.

Bayesian optimization has been used previously for this challenge.

Contextual bandits could possibly be used. However, I could not find any examples.

What are the best options for hyperparameter search in non-stationary environments?